# Standalone APIService needs access to redux or NextJS ctx for getting token

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, next.js

I have a standalone APIService.js which is used across my NextJS Application, it does a few things, but the main thing is setting the BASE_URL and if the user has logged in (should have a token in a cookie, or in a header cookie - this then dispatches into redux).

Basically I think I need this APIService to either; detect when there is a cookie on the machine (it does) or if its server-side rendered and get it from the header; or what I think is better - is to listen for changes to redux, and take the token from the redux store.

This is my APIService here;

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
    import { API_URL } from './constants';

    const config = {
      baseURL: API_URL,
    };
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const APIService = axios.create(config);

    APIService.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
      const token = cookies.get('token');
      request.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
      return request;
    });

    export default APIService;
```

to give an example of the NextJS page usage;

I have this function in my _app.js

```
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    if (ctx.isServer) {
      if (ctx.req.headers.cookie) {
        const token = getCookie('token', ctx.req);
        console.log('WHOAMI ', token);
        ctx.store.dispatch(reauthenticate(token));
      }
    } else {
      const { token } = ctx.store.getState().authentication;
      console.log('WHOAMI2 ', token);
      ctx.store.dispatch(reauthenticate(token));
    }

    return {
      pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
        ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        : {},
    };
  }
```

Do I need to connect() the APIService to Redux - if so how can I? I generally import the APIService into other components where I need to use my API, so i dont want to make drastic changes to it unless absolutely necessary.

I did add a context hook to the page itself to call the API client side, but this only works as a workaround for the fact I cannot get access to the header or token in the APIService as it has no context access.

So I could add a function like this to the pages, but I know its a horrid solution.

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

Answer (score 1):

I find that if you want something to always be up-to-date with Redux, it's best to write a [`reselect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) selector for it.  Something like:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getAuth = (state:AppState) => state.auth;

const getToken = createSelector(getAuth, (auth) => auth.token);

// Easy syntax for class-based services
const getSimpleService = createSelector(getToken, (token) => {
  return new Service(token);
})

// Your sample APIService
const getApiService = createSelector(getToken, (token) => {
    const config = {
      baseURL: API_URL,
    };
    const APIService = axios.create(config);

    APIService.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
      request.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
      return request;
    });

    return APIService;
})
```

Now your components can get the API through `connect()`!  My experience is with React rather than Next, but the Redux code ought to be pretty much the same.  Refactoring your API service into a class might also be convenient, as you could keep all the axios setup in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In our application, what we did is we kept the services, particularly the Authentication Service, decoupled from Redux.

What I would suggest is to keep using it in the `getInitialProps` instead of connecting it to redux directly. You can still use it on redux without any problems too as you only need access to the Cookies to make the login check work. It will do the job and will keep things simple.

Comment: But how to connect this standalone function in the best way to getInitialProps? Any references you can provide or ideally code examples? Does it need to be a HOC?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend context with hooks

#### Controllers

```
import React from 'react';

import { NextPage, NextPageContext } from 'next';

import Layout from '@layouts/index';
import { AuthStore, AuthStoreProps } from '@src/stores';

interface HomeProps {
  cookie?: string;
}

const HomeController: NextPage<HomeProps> = ({ cookie }) => {
  const authStore = React.useContext<AuthStoreProps>(AuthStore);
  const isAuthorized = authStore.getAuthentication(cookie);

  return <Layout>Home</Layout>;
};

HomeController.getInitialProps = async ({ req }: NextPageContext) => {
  const cookie = req ? req.headers.cookie : '';
  return { cookie };
};

export default HomeController;
```

#### Hooks

Your API Services

#### Opinions

You can control store values using class and context.
and then This could be reused in react or js projects.
React was concentrated on functional programming with hooks. you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't quite follow this example seems to jump quite beyond what my example code was...